# Is it okay to write funny rejection messages for Community suggested review audits?

Tags: discussion, community-user

Has anyone else taken to writing a special custom message for the [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3437984) by the [Community ♦ user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)?

> **Why are you rejecting this edit:**
>
> - Because the Community is testing me!
> - I don't wanna be scolded for accepting it.
> - I don't trust robot edits.

Is there an issue with leaving small humorous messages? ***IF*** the post turns out to be a real, bad edit, it's still been rejected, just not for the ideal reason.

Comment: Are you referring to the review audits, which are incredibly easy to spot? Or suggestions from anonymous users that get attributed to the Community user if accepted?

Comment: @animuson an audit would end upon hitting "reject", you never get to the point of selecting a reason.

Comment: @Servy: Not for suggested edits. It ends when you click the "Reject" button after choosing a rejection reason. FWIW, I used to type humorous rejection reasons, but quickly got bored and now just reject them as "Vandalism".

Comment: Yeah, I meant review audits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meh. As I said in my [comments on Servy's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208920/is-it-okay-to-write-funny-rejection-messages-for-community-suggested-review-audi#comment667452_208921), the reason you write doesn't show up on the site ***anywhere***, so I really see no harm in doing so.

I used to write custom rejection reasons... usually asking the Community user questions (how his day was, what he had for tea, plans for the weekend etc.).

After several weeks of getting ignored however, I directed my efforts elsewhere, and now just use the "Vandalism" rejection reason.

Comment: +1 for being ignored by the community user! (Separately, nice to see use of the word [tea](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/125102/21740))

Comment: @JamesWebster: Haha, [busted](http://toys.usvsth3m.com/north-o-meter/).

Comment: I used to leave comments like “enough with the #&*(&()# audits”, and then I stopped reviewing.

Answer (score 6):

I like humor as much as the next guy, but this isn't a good place for it.  The rejection reason can be very useful information for people reading it, or very confusing and harmful if incorrect or used incorrectly.

It can still be seen by other reviewers seeing what others thought, trying to learn how to better review, for example, or by the post author who gets a notification of the edit.  It's also conceivable, albeit unlikely, that the anonymous user who suggested the edit is going to keep track of it to see what happens.

Comment: If the OP is talking about rejecting Suggested Edit audits, this answer is invalid as the rejection reason doesn't show up anywhere (it's perfectly correct for rejecting anonymous/ "Community" edits however, of course).

Comment: @Matt It shows up on the review page, when someone goes back to look at it.  My answer described several situations in which someone might go look at it.

Comment: Like I said, not for review audits. It just says "Review Audit Passed/Failed". See http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3437984